# Rendering state right after updating the state (react)

Tags: reactjs

Im just wondering how i can stop the function from returning before the state has been updated - Here is my code so i can explain more clearly.

```
    const mockData = {
    current: {
        temperature: 'loading'
    }
}
export default function Weather({ city }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(mockData)
    const url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=2cbe1b14f771abee0713f93317e1b107&query=${city}`
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
            setData(data, () => { })
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Weather</h1>
            <p>temperature: {data.current.temperature}</p>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Right now i am using mockData because if i dont i will get an error because the .current.temperature properties do not exist (because set state hasnt been updated yet).
How can i stop the error and stop the div being returned before the set state has been updated or atleast stop the error and return an empy div or something.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a conditional within your return.

Try this:

```js
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Weather</h1>
    <p>Temperature: {(data && data.current) ? data.current.temperature : ""}</p>
  </div>
)
```

You can also use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to achieve the same result.

```js
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Weather</h1>
    <p>Temperature: {data?.current?.temperature || ""}</p>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thats a cool idea thank you, Is this standard? Im unsure of what im doing is hacky or not - I had the same issue with the input of a form but had to hack my way around it

Comment: What is likely better practice would be to have some sort of boolean flag that specifies that the data is being fetched and then have some sort of loading UI that displays while it's fetching.

Comment: Kind of like the 'const = [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)'? Then only return if the boolean has updated to true through useState

Comment: Yep pretty much! And then you can setLoading(false) inside the then section of the promise that fetches the data (within the useEffect)

Comment: Similarly, depending on your UI, you may want to have a const[errored, setErrored] = useState(false); then add a .catch to your fetch promise and setErrored(true) inside there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `data` exists before you reference `data.current`, and you need to check that `data.current` exists before you reference `data.current.temperature`. If you access a property of `undefined`, your code will crash.

You need to have some additional state, such as `isLoading`

If you want a hack, you can do this:

```
export default function Weather({ city }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(mockData)
    const url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=2cbe1b14f771abee0713f93317e1b107&query=${city}`
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
            setData(data, () => { })
        })
    }, [])

    function renderTemperature() {
      if (!data) {
        return null;
      } else if (data && !data.current) {
        return null;
      } else if (data.current && data.current.temperature) {
        return <p>temperature: {data.current.temperature}</p>
      }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Weather</h1>
            { renderTemperature() }
        </div>
    )
}

Much better solution:


export default function Weather({ city }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=2cbe1b14f771abee0713f93317e1b107&query=${city}`
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => {
            setData(data, () => { })
            setIsLoaded(true);
        })
    }, [])

    function renderTemperature() {
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Weather</h1>
            { isLoaded ? <p>temperature: {data.current.temperature}</p> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Cheers, Im currently using something like that now - But i havent got any state for the isLoaded. Is there any reason why using state is better than just doing this         <p>temperature: {data.current ? data.current.temperature : 'loading'}</p>

Comment: @ST you might have more deep nesting beyond just `data.current.temperature`. Imagine an object like `{ data: { current: { temperature: { actual: 50, windchill: 40 } } } }` - If 4 layers deep,  you will need to make the ternary function more confusing.